# Able to float td elements consistently?

Tags: html, css, css-float, compatibility, html-table

It's getting late and I'm rapidly losing the ability to think.

Is it possible to float `<td>` elements consistently across a few decent browsers? Seems to work in Firefox, I hear Bad Things about IE but then I'm free of those shackles for this project. Really, I'm concerned about Chrome's lack of want to play.

EDIT: If it helps at all, I am extremely lax about browser compliance this time 'round, I expect deploying this app only to a controlled user group, and its a tool, not a model of perfect code - so I'm willing to blind-eye a dirty hack if there's one going.

Comment: Why would you need to flaot a TD? Tables are meant to be fixed!

Comment: Agreed, but its a TinyMCE configuration, I'm being demanded for a single line of edit tools, which stack once the fluid layout starts collapsing.

Comment: Well that's just awful. Do you have some sourcecode we can see?

Comment: The quickest source is http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/example_24.php. That ones not resizing via window or anything, but it is behaving like my example is, notice the TinyMCE custom resize handle stops resizing downward when it hits the row boundary. My example is tied into a local, specific server setup unfortunately :/

Answer (score 0):

While floating td is weird and shouldn't be done, my call would be to make them `display:block` before trying anything else.

I'd need to see some code in order to be more specific about what to do.

Comment: I've tried inline-block, inline, table, and then all of the weird ones I ever use like run-in :P In any event, floating would switch us to block, unless td's behave differently, but then they may well do!