# Tiny_mce - can't set width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tinymce

Let me start by saying I am well aware this is a duplicate question - [TinyMCE width and height disobedient!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436934/tinymce-width-and-height-disobedient)

The trouble is I have tried all the css fixe suggested to no avail and I am not using an init (where the docs i found tell you to set your width and height) - I dont know why, I did this along time ago.
Here is the mce code which is being launched in an aftershow event of a fancybox:

```
  $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
            // Location of TinyMCE script
            script_url: '/assets/js/common/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

            // General options
            theme: "advanced",
            plugins: "autolink,lists,pagebreak,table,advlink,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,advlist",

            // Theme options
            theme_advanced_buttons1: "undo,redo,|,cut,copy,paste,|,bold,italic,underline,|,forecolor,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,sub,sup,|,formatselect,fontsizeselect",
            theme_advanced_buttons2: "tablecontrols,|,charmap,iespell,|,cite,abbr,acronym,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,link,unlink,|,fullscreen",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
            theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
            theme_advanced_resizing: false
            });
```

Please someone, tell me how to make this god damn thing 500px wide. I tried this(does nothing):

```
.mceEditor > table {
    width:500px !important;
}
```

Tried putting this in general options in my code:

```
width:"500",
```

Tried setting columns of the textarea to 2

Tried setting the css width of the following elements with !important:

```
id=desc_mce_parent,  id="desc_mce_tbl"
```

I have set resizing to false

Nothing changes no matter what I do - why?

Comment: wild guess: see if you can use an ID somewhere in that selector (e.g. `#someContainer > .mceEditor > table { ... }` as your class selector will be overriden by any ID selectors.

Comment: @jbabey Thanks for the suggestion, just tried it but no joy... it's nearly time for nicedit

Comment: +1 i suggest you post your answer as an answer and accept it after two days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... I feel a bit of an idiot saying this but in my case it was because my toolbars were too big. I solved this by spreading my buttons over three toolbars - you can set the width using css but it wont go smaller than your toolbars and the they will not wrap around (seems like that might be a good feature).