# How to change the size of the tinymce jquery box?

Tags: jquery, tinymce, width

I need to change the width of the tinymce's box to fit in my design and I don't know how. I searched the Internet and didn't find anything related to the width of the jquery version of tinymce.

```
<!-- Load jQuery build -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{BASE_URL}/js/tiny_mce/jquery.tinymce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

                $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
                        // Location of TinyMCE script
                        script_url : '{BASE_URL}/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

                        // General options
                        theme : "advanced",             
                        plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

                        // Theme options
                        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
                        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
                        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
                        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
                        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
                        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
                        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

                        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
                        content_css : "css/content.css",

                        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
                        template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
                        external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
                        external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
                        media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

                        // Replace values for the template plugin
                        template_replace_values : {
                                username : "Some User",
                                staffid : "991234"
                        }
                });
        });


</script>

<td>Description: </td><td><textarea style="height:150px;" name="description" class=" tinymce"></textarea></td> //textarea
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to configure width of your tinymce editor? See http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:width

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        width : "840"
});
```

for jQuery:

```
$(function() {

     $('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
         //...
         width: "840"
     });
});
```

Check also this fiddle http://fiddle.tinymce.com/eaaaab

**Enabling too many buttons in one line prevents you from making the editor more narrow.**

Comment: added code also for jQuery, try to play also on attached fiddle page

Comment: Consider if all buttons you have there configured you really need, because it seems that tinymce is not able to shrink more than width of all buttons you have in longest line

Answer (score 1):

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    width : "640"
    // width: '100%',
});
```

Check [HERE](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3awidth)

Answer (score 1):

I am using the jQuery plugin version in my projects. This is what you need:

```
$(selector).tinymce({
    theme: 'advanced', // basic or advanced
    theme_advanced_resizing : false,
    theme_advanced_resize_horizontal: false,
    theme_advanced_resizing_max_width: '500',
    theme_advanced_resizing_min_height: '300',
    width: '500',
    height: '300'
});
```

If you want to force the width using CSS, try this:

```
.mceEditor > table {
    width: 200px !important;
}
```

See ([TinyMCE width and height disobedient!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436934/tinymce-width-and-height-disobedient))

Comment: I found out that it works but I can't set the width to less than 300, and i need it 200 :)

Comment: i forgot to remove the inline when i posted, but i don't use inline style to size it. but i can't resize it under 300 or something :) thanx for help anyway :D

Comment: Have you tried remove some buttons because it seems editor cannot be shrinked more than width of all buttons you have in longest line (+ some margins of course).