# TinyMCE height disobedient in my angular app

Tags: angularjs, tinymce, wysiwyg

I'm trying to change the height of my TinyMCE box in my angular app which I find very small.

So I just applied what I read on the (conflicting) documentation of TinyMCE.
Therefore, I've something like :

```
 $scope.optionTinyMCE = {
            language: "fr_FR",
            selector: "textarea",
              height: 700, // This is what I added, but nothing change
            statusbar: false,
            menubar: false,
            plugins: [
                "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
                "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
            ],
            toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"

        };
```

But it doesn't work at all, I still have my tiny height. 
I also tried to apply what I read in this very [interesting post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436934/tinymce-width-and-height-disobedient), but my issue remains.

How to overcome this ?

Answer (score 0):

You've to refresh your editor in case you do any change on it's properties. Give a try to this approach (Call changeHeight function in any button click).

```js
$scope.editorHeight = "700px";
$scope.optionTinyMCE = {
            language: "fr_FR",
            selector: "textarea",
              height: $scope.editorHeight, // This is what I added, but nothing change
            statusbar: false,
            menubar: false,
            plugins: [
                "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
                "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
            ],
            toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter      alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
};

//Call this on button click
$scope.changeHeight = function(){
   $scope.editorHeight = "1000px";
   $scope.$broadcast('$tinymce:refresh');   
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work! tinyMCE is refreshing but the height remains the same   

Comment: I used the same approach and it works. If you can make a snippet or jsfiddle with minimal ui-tinymce we might test it.